# How can I rotate my image at an offset from the center using OpenGL and Java?

Tags: java, opengl

Hello I am trying to rotate my image from an offset but anytime I attempt to translate something other than the center it stops rendering my image. I am fairly new to OpenGL and I understand that the way I am using it is "old fashioned" but I was told if I use this method I would better understand how OpenGL works.

drawImage

```
    public static void drawImage(ImageResource image, float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        GL2 gl = EventListener.gl;

        Texture texture = image.getTexture();

        if(texture != null) {
            gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureObject());
        }

        //Below is where I offset to the position I provide but when I add something to the x or y my image doesn't render
        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glColor4f(red, green, blue, alpha);
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
            gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            gl.glVertex2f(-width / 2, -height / 2);

            gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            gl.glVertex2f(width / 2, -height / 2);

            gl.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            gl.glVertex2f(width / 2, height / 2);

            gl.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            gl.glVertex2f(-width / 2, height / 2);
        gl.glEnd();
        gl.glFlush();

        gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

        gl.glRotatef(-rotation, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0);
    }
```

Below is the image I am rotating and I drew a circle overtop of it. The center of the image is somewhere between his arm and the rifle and I would like to offset it so that the image rotates about where his head is.

[image: Image to Rotate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measure the distance to the center of the head (`pvot_x,`, `pivot_y`) and rotate around the pivot point. Use [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) instead of doing the inverse matrix operations:

```java
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(x + pivot_x, y + pivot_y, 0);
gl.glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);
gl.glTranslatef(-pivot_x, -pivot_y, 0);

// draw mesh
// [...]

gl.glPopMatrix();

// DELETE
// gl.glRotatef(-rotation, 0, 0, 1);
// gl.glTranslatef(-x, -y, 0);
```